# HttpWebRequest how to read server response when status returned is 400 Bad Request

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I'm hitting a 3rd party shipping API and testing bad requests, like a bad ship date.  The API accepts an XML request and returns an XML response which may be formatted as an error response. In the case of an error the server returns a status of 400 Bad Request. However my code throws an error at that point and there is no response body. The API folks say they are sending an XML response and a 400 status.

How can I handle (or ignore) the 400 status and receive the xml response?

```
myRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(myURL), HttpWebRequest)
myRequest.Method = "POST"
myRequest.ContentType = "application/xml"
myRequest.ContentLength = Data.Length

NewStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream()
NewStream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length)
NewStream.Close()
Try
    myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse() 'Error thrown here
    SR = New StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream())
    response = SR.ReadToEnd()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Comment: Unfortunately, WebRequest throws when a StatusCode value above 399 is set. You can catch `WebException`. The exception object returns the WebResponse and its content (when set). The Response also returns the last `StatusCode`, of course.

Comment: @Jimi - brilliant! Works perfectly.  sr = New StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream())

Comment: Remember to post your findings as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
Try
    myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse()
    sr = New StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream())
    response = sr.ReadToEnd()
Catch wex As WebException
    sr = New StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
    response = sr.ReadToEnd()
End Try
```